# Unknown Error while trying to play sound

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myself/Desktop/iOS Development/X Code Projects/myproject/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/myself/Desktop/iOS Development/X Code Projects/myproject/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox (2 slices)
```

I Need to Solve it the fast the best!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need import frame AudioToolBox, Try it.

```
       #import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

Comment: i've imported it on the .h file